# Icon in Tab QML

Tags: mobile, tabs, qml, tabview

I was looking in documentation of QML but I didn't find:

- Is there any way to insert image into `Tab` in `TabView` in QML?
- Is there possibility of scrolling `Tabs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@folibis is right, but with his permission, I'd like to show you an example as it may be difficult to understand how to set an image in QML tabs.

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Example")


    TabView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Tab { title: "One" ; Item {}}
        Tab { title: "Two" ; Item {}}
        Tab { title: "Three" ; Item {}}
        Tab { title: "Four" ; Item {}}
        style: tabViewStyle
    }

    Component {
        id: tabViewStyle
        TabViewStyle {
            tabsMovable: true

            tab: Item {
                implicitWidth: 97
                implicitHeight: 28

                Image {
                    id: image
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    source: styleData.selected ? "images/tab_selected.png" : "images/tab.png"
                }
                Text {
                    id: text
                    text: styleData.selected ? "" : styleData.title
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                }
            }

            frame: Rectangle { color: "steelblue" }
        }
    }
}
```

I [uploaded](https://github.com/ftena/qt-snippets/tree/master/qml-styles) the code to GitHub.

**Updated**

You can use some `TabViewStyle` properties to load different images depending on your requirements. I.e. the next code is using `int styleData.index` to load different `sources`. The code is also in GitHub.

```
        TabViewStyle {
            tabsMovable: true

            tab: Item {
                function loadImage(index) {
                    return "images/tab"+index+".png";
                }

                implicitWidth: 97
                implicitHeight: 28

                Image {
                    id: image
                    anchors.centerIn: parent                        
                    source: loadImage(styleData.index)
                }
                Text {
                    id: text
                    text: styleData.selected ? "" : styleData.title
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                }
            }

            frame: Rectangle { color: "steelblue" }
        }
```

Comment: How could I do something like: 
`text: styleData.selected ? {image:source=loadImage(styleData.title+"Active.png") }:{ image:source=loadImage(styleData.title)}`

Comment: I think in that case you need to set source as `source: styleData.selected ? "images/tab_selected.png" : "images/tab.png"` and the text always with the tab text: `text: styleData.title` You don't need the function, do you?